# Why a set is weakly sequentially precompact set?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I'm struggling to understand the following assertion:

> Since $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\|x(t)-y_0\|$ exists, $\{x(t):t\geq 0\}$ is weakly sequentially precompact.

Please give thorough explanations because my knowledge of weak topology is very weak (pun intended ;) )

If something is unclear, please refer to this paper: [Asymptotic convergence of nonlinear contraction semigroups](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022123675900270/1-s2.0-0022123675900270-main.pdf?_tid=941af77d-1b1d-4cae-8feb-36b89e476d4f&acdnat=1534326405_781ccad7402bfaab1f8ffbe342342f54), (theorem 1 -- at the end of page 17 and beginning of page 18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is continuous the image of $[0,N]$ is is norm bounded for each positive integer $N$. Since $\lim_{t \to \infty} \|x(t)-y_0\|$ exists it follows that $\{x(t): t \geq 0\}$ lies in a norm bounded subset of $H$. In a separable Hilbert space any norm bounded set is weakly sequentially precompact.

Comment: Where can I find that any norm bounded set is weakly sequentially precompact? Sorry I'm being pedantic but as I said I know very little about weak topology.

Comment: Actually this requires some knowledge of weak and weak* topologies. The Banach-Alaoglu Theorem (which can be found in many texts in Functional Analysis says that the closed unit ball of a dual space is compact in the weak* topology. Since Hilbert spaces are reflexive the weak* topology coincides with the weak topology and separability guarantees existence of weakly convergent.  subsequence . Lot of reading to do but you can start with Banach-Alaoglu Theorem .

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated.

Comment: I hope this gets some interest. I have encountered a problem: in the article I mentioned the hilbert space need not to be separable. How can one prove then that the set is weakly sequentially precompact?

Comment: There is no loss of generality in assuming that $H$ is separeble: to prove that the set is weakly sequentially compact you have to start with a sequence $\{x(t_n)\}$ and show there is a weakly convergent subsequence. Once this sequence is given you can work within the Hilbert space generated by this sequence (which is separable).